# NextJS build fails but does not tell why

Tags: next.js

When I try to build a NextJS project I get an error message `Build error ocurred`.

Is there a way to get more information about the error?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there is a good way to run the next build in a `verbose` format.

Have you considered creating a custom webpack config and perhaps running it in debug mode to gain more knowledge?